# Remove NewtonSoft JsonSerialization information

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

When I try to serialize with `Object` datatype in ASP.NET WebApi, unwanted properties are contained.

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public SomeViewModel(Object item, SomeItemType itemType)
    {
        Item = item;
        ItemType = itemType;
    }

    public Object Item { get; set; }
    public SomeItemType ItemType { get; set; }
}
```

With above model, the JSON result is as below. I pointed out **unwanted properties**.

```
{
"$id": "20",
"Result": { // here the item comes.
  "$id": "21",
  "Id": 1005227636,
  "UserName": null,
  "Locale": 0,
  "Grade": 0
},
"Id": 10, // unwanted properties.
"Exception": null,
"Status": 5,
"IsCanceled": false,
"IsCompleted": true,
"CreationOptions": 0,
"AsyncState": null,
"IsFaulted": false
}
```

I don't know the unwanted properties if from NewtonSoft.Json or ASP.NET pipeline, but it seems like serialization information is inserted along with the result.

How can I omit unwanted properties? It does not produce when I serialize strongly defined classes.

Comment: What about http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm ?

Comment: @oakio // unfortunately, that's not the case I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, my bad.

```
Select(async o => item.ThisIsNotAsyncMethod());
```

The execution code in linq had `async` keyword which was not a asynchronous task. Remove async than it works. (a little quizzy. I thought that `async` keyword was just a syntatic sugar for `await` and not affects compile result. maybe I misunderstood)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair // thanks for teaching me with wonderful article :)

Comment: ;) nevermind ... it's just syntatic sugar (like all the new stuff, eg `var`, `??`, `select` ...)